# Lock a hardware resource to a Container (Docker)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, containers, hardware

Is there a way to lock a hardware resource to a Container running on Docker framework / Ubuntu

Example : I want to lock a network interface card only to a given container and no other container shall be able to access the NIC directly/ even lock GPIO to one container, etc.

Thanks,
PT

Comment: Your question is a bit too general. Binding NIC to docker containers would work differently than binding other hardware (like GPUs) to them. Please specify. Also, should this be exclusive (as in - only docker can use the NIC)?

Comment: Hi, thanks, i'll check. My issue is more towards restricting access to a hardware addon chip / some card on the motherboard to a specific container, I want to lock a secure flash interface or a TPM chip to a container. So that only a selected container has full control of the hardware chip to provide hardware access to other containers as a service, rather than N number of containers accessing the hardware resource in the async and unpredicatable fashion

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lock network interface card or network layer of the underlying hardware, then you need to use docker in host mode.

```
docker run --net=host -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Currently, there's no way to lock a hardware resource to specific docker container. By default, there's no constraint on resources when you run a docker container but you can limit how much resources it can consume (memory, cpu, IO, etc).

You can refer in this [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/) on how to limit a container resource.

Comment: thanks, i'll check. 

My issue is more towards restricting access to a hardware addon chip / some card on the motherboard to a specific container.  I want to lock a secure flash interface or a TPM chip to a container. So that only a selected container has full control of the hardware chip to provide hardware access to other containers as a service, rather than N number of containers accessing the hardware resource in the async and unpredicatable fashion